# How to share file using Google Drive API v3

Tags: php, google-drive-api

I wanted to programmatically share my files stored in google drive with some users. I have tried to use a code provided by google but I couldn't get started as it results in an error.

I have configured the web cient id and secret code from developers console. I have also downloaded the files. What exactly I need to do to get started. I

```
use Google\Client;
use Google\Service\Drive;

require_once 'vendor\autoload.php';
function shareFile()
{
    try {
        $client = new Client();
        $client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();
        $client->addScope(Drive::DRIVE);
        $driveService = new Drive($client);
        $realFileId = readline("1Mk2rrKibgh5SMKV4zKPBUVyc31-hvzeK");
        $realUser = readline("mydrive_email@gmail.com");
        $realDomain = readline("Enter domain name: ");
        $ids = array();
            $fileId = '1sTWaJ_j7PkjzaBWtNc3IzovK5hQf21FbOw9yLeeLPNQ';
            $fileId = $realFileId;
            $driveService->getClient()->setUseBatch(true);
            try {
                $batch = $driveService->createBatch();

                $userPermission = new Drive\Permission(array([
                    'type' => 'user',
                    'role' => 'writer',
                    'emailAddress' => 'user@example.com'
                ]));
                $userPermission['emailAddress'] = $realUser;
                $request = $driveService->permissions->create(
                    $fileId, $userPermission, array(['fields' => 'id']));
                $batch->add($request, 'user');
                $domainPermission = new Drive\Permission(array([
                    'type' => 'domain',
                    'role' => 'reader',
                    'domain' => 'example.com'
                ]));
                $userPermission['domain'] = $realDomain;
                $request = $driveService->permissions->create(
                    $fileId, $domainPermission, array(['fields' => 'id']));
                $batch->add($request, 'domain');
                $results = $batch->execute();

                foreach ($results as $result) {
                    if ($result instanceof Google_Service_Exception) {
                        // Handle error
                        printf($result);
                    } else {
                        printf("Permission ID: %s\n", $result->id);
                        array_push($ids, $result->id);
                    }
                }
            } finally {
                $driveService->getClient()->setUseBatch(false);
            }
            return $ids;
    } catch(Exception $e) {
        echo "Error Message: ".$e;
    }

}
shareFile();
?>
```

Running the above code produces the following error
Notice: Indirect modification of overloaded property Google\Service\Drive\Permission::$teamDrivePermissionDetails has no effect in D:\Personal\Xamp\htdocs\google-drive\vendor\google\apiclient\src\Collection.php on line 100

Notice: Undefined index: type in D:\Personal\Xamp\htdocs\google-drive\vendor\google\apiclient\src\Service\Resource.php on line 281

Notice: Undefined index: location in D:\Personal\Xamp\htdocs\google-drive\vendor\google\apiclient\src\Service\Resource.php on line 284

Notice: Undefined index: location in D:\Personal\Xamp\htdocs\google-drive\vendor\google\apiclient\src\Service\Resource.php on line 286

Notice: Indirect modification of overloaded property Google\Service\Drive\Permission::$teamDrivePermissionDetails has no effect in D:\Personal\Xamp\htdocs\google-drive\vendor\google\apiclient\src\Collection.php on line 100

Notice: Undefined index: type in D:\Personal\Xamp\htdocs\google-drive\vendor\google\apiclient\src\Service\Resource.php on line 281

Notice: Undefined index: location in D:\Personal\Xamp\htdocs\google-drive\vendor\google\apiclient\src\Service\Resource.php on line 284

Notice: Undefined index: location in D:\Personal\Xamp\htdocs\google-drive\vendor\google\apiclient\src\Service\Resource.php on line 286
Error Message: DomainException: Could not load the default credentials. Browse to https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/application-default-credentials for more information in D:\Personal\Xamp\htdocs\google-drive\vendor\google\auth\src\ApplicationDefaultCredentials.php:189 Stack trace: #0 D:\Personal\Xamp\htdocs\google-drive\vendor\google\apiclient\src\Client.php(1247): Google\Auth\ApplicationDefaultCredentials::getCredentials('https://www.goo...', Object(Google\Auth\HttpHandler\Guzzle7HttpHandler), Array, Object(Google\Auth\Cache\MemoryCacheItemPool), NULL) #1 D:\Personal\Xamp\htdocs\google-drive\vendor\google\apiclient\src\Client.php(433): Google\Client->createApplicationDefaultCredentials() #2 D:\Personal\Xamp\htdocs\google-drive\vendor\google\apiclient\src\Client.php(913): Google\Client->authorize() #3 D:\Personal\Xamp\htdocs\google-drive\vendor\google\apiclient\src\Http\Batch.php(138): Google\Client->execute(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request)) #4 D:\Personal\Xamp\htdocs\google-drive\quickstart.php(41): Google\Http\Batch->execute() #5 D:\Personal\Xamp\htdocs\google-drive\quickstart.php(61): shareFile() #6 {main}

Comment: Have you tried running the same code or the "permissions.create" portion separated and using a different ID of a file that you know is shareable? Are you sharing the file with Google Workspace users or Gmail users?

Comment: I just couldn't get started. I tried to run the code but resulted in the above error. I am trying to share the file my email address own to other Gmail users.

Comment: That particular error is not linked to Drive API itself, it is more of an array error on how you have the PHP configured.

Comment: I don't know what wrong I did